# Adobe Experience Manager package

Tags: adobe

Does Adobe Experience Manager have Adobe cloud included in the package when you purchased it or is it a separate product/service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Experience Cloud is a suite of software products across marketing, analytics, advertising, and commerce that includes Adobe Experience Manager. The reverse is not true - Adobe Experience Manager does not include Adobe Experience Cloud, but Adobe Experience Manager *does* include a native connection to Adobe Creative Cloud.

Comment: Adobe Creative Cloud is not included either.

Comment: thank you. Can I use other cloud services? not just Adobe?

Comment: Adobe has a toll free phone number link at: https://www.adobe.com/marketing/experience-manager.html at the bottom of the page which you can call to ask whether you can use a specific cloud service with Adobe Experience Manager.